# How to load jQuery scripts in every component?

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm building a single page application using Angular2 and the Limitless layout.
However, there is an app.js file in the theme that contains all the jQuery functionality.
I have loaded it in the index.html but the jQuery only works when I refresh the page.

How can I modify the app.js to make the jQuery function inside run in every component?

Comment: are you working with angular-cli ?

Comment: @YoavSchniederman Yes I am

Comment: So, First run npm install --save jquery at your root directory with cmd. than you need to add at angular-cli.json the jquery path to scripts array : "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
      ]   and than you can use "declare var $ : any;" at your ts file

Answer (score 0):

create function in `app.js` ie.

```
function executeEveryCompo(){
      console.log('Something');
}
```

and in every component `AfterviewInit` add

```
ngAfterviewInit(){
     executeEveryCompo();
}
```

dont forget to add `declare var executeEveryCompo:any;` at the top of component

Answer (score 0):

Before the Component Decorator, use

```
// You can use $ to refer to jQuery inside the code
declare var $ : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  providers: []
})
```